# c# - WebClient - downloading HTML data to variable

Tags: c#, header, webclient, downloadstring

I am dealing with theoretically simple WebClient request.
All was working fine till this Sunday and apparently the site has changed something on their level.

What I did is (simplified for analysis - both HTTP and HTTPS give the same result):

```
string strRemoteFileNameGPW = @"http://www.gpw.pl/ajaxindex.php?action=GPWQuotations&start=showTable&tab=all&lang=PL&type=&full=1&format=html&download_xls=1";
```

and next (with or without a proxy) this was working fine (e.g. using HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument).

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
 string strResult = webClient.DownloadString(strRemoteFileNameGPW);
}
```

Not sure what changed, so I tried to review StackOverflow and tried all stuff here.
Nothing worked, or I am finally blind ... and overlooked some obvious thing.

I tried to listen the traffic and finally even added some headers, trying to be closer to regular browser:

```
 webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
 // webClient.Headers.Add("Host", "www.gpw.pl");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");
 // webClient.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
 webClient.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
 webClient.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "Windows");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Site", "none");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Mode", "navigate");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-User", "?1");
 webClient.Headers.Add("Sec-Fetch-Dest", "document");
 webClient.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "Windows");
 webClient.Headers.Add("sec-ch-ua-platform", "Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"98\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"98");
```

**Expected result** - get the displayed result and save for further parsing of data.

Nothing helps and I keep getting exception **"An error occurred while sending the request."** and inner exception **"Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"**.

Firewall, AV disabled. Tried on other machines. Same result. What am I missing? This was perfectly working before. Did they notice my requests and blocked requests like mine somehow?

Comment: Nope, they just moved to `https`. Change your URL to https and It will work.

Comment: @Eldar I already did this try before posting this, https does not work either.

Comment: Also you should not add a Host header. Also this header :`"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"`

Answer (score 1):

It seems the server expects the `Connection: keep-alive` header.

By the way: check out the [remark on WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-6.0#remarks). I suggest you use the [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0) instead.

An example that seems to work:

```
var url @"http://www.gpw.pl/ajaxindex.php?action=GPWQuotations&start=showTable&tab=all&lang=PL&type=&full=1&format=html&download_xls=1";

using var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.ParseAdd("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Connection.ParseAdd("keep-alive");

var strResult = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

See [the fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VV5j7n) in action